# ASP.NET/VB Format won't change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an API feed in which it feeding me data in a dollar amount. I am getting, for example, $850,000.00 through the data feed. In the code, there's nothing I can do to change the format no matter what I try.

```html
<div id="propcost" style="font-size: 20pt;color:#F00; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ListingPrice","0:N0")%>'></asp:Label>

                            </div>
```

The number this way is coming thru with a "$" through the data feed but I need to get rid of the two decimal places and nothing is working

Comment: Do you want to keep the dollar sign? The comma? Do you want to round if you drop the cents / everything past the decimal?

Comment: The dollar sign doesn't matter. I just won't to remove the decimal places. I only want to see $800,000 instead of $800,000.00 The formatting I tried haven't worked at all so Im stuck

Comment: Can you remove the `Text=` part and, in the code-behind, use `Label14.Text = ListingPrice.ToString("N0")`? Or is the problem that `ListingPrice` is a string and not a number?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are databinding to a source where ListingPrice is a string.  Strings do not respond to the {0:N0} format.  **I would prefer to convert and format the data PRIOR to databinding so that you can handle problems in code and not blowup your view (ASPX).**  Having said that...

```
<div id="propcost" style="font-size: 20pt; color: #F00; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Double.Parse(Eval("ListingPrice").ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency ).ToString("N0")%>'></asp:Label>
</div>
```

We're doing a lot in the binding, first Eval(…)ToString() is needed because Decimal.Parse needs a string and not an object. Then Decimal.Parse converts to a decimal type accepting '$' and ','. And finally back to string using whatever numeric format you'd like.